# Checking to see if an element is in a tree in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write the rules for a predicate in Prolog that will see if a particular member (E) is in a given tree. The tree is not BST, it's like an unsorted binary tree. I can't figure out what is wrong with the logic in the code below.

```
treeMember(E, node(X, _, _)).
treeMember(E, node(X, L, _)) :- 
    treeMember(E, L).
treeMember(E, node(X, _, R)) :-  
    treeMember(E, R).
```

The given example query is

```
?-treeMember(3,node(1, node(2, node(3,nil,nil),node(4,nil,nil)), node(5,nil,nil))).
```

and that should give a '''true''', which the code does but it'll always give a `true` even when the (E) in question is not part of the tree. May I please have some pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the first clause when E must be unifiable with X.

```
treeMember(E, node(E, _, _)) :- !.
treeMember(E, node(_, L, _)) :- 
    L \= nil,
    treeMember(E, L).
treeMember(E, node(_, _, R)) :-  
    R \= nil,
    treeMember(E, R).
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That really helps. I'll have to read up more about this it seems.

Comment: Note that you don't need the `L \= nil` and `R \= nil` tests. Also `R` is missing in the head of the last clause.

Comment: Thanks to @PauloMoura